How to do Song Track list with fragment in Android Studio?
I'm new in android studio, just learned about a week. Before this project , I made a simple SongTrackList using main activity with no fragment, it can run smooth (click ImageButton , audio works). Now i use fragment to do my SongTrackList, no error message but audio not work(No sound).
This below is last project code:
(MainActivity.java)
package com.example.songbuttoninlistview;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private SongAdapter adapter;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private List<Song> songList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.lv);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        songList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Add your songs to the songList
        songList.add(new Song("Name1", R.raw.song1, R.drawable.songPic1));
        songList.add(new Song("Name2", R.raw.song2, R.drawable.songPic2));
        songList.add(new Song("Name3", R.raw.song3, R.drawable.songPic3));
        songList.add(new Song("Name4", R.raw.song4, R.drawable.songPic4));
        songList.add(new Song("Name5", R.raw.song5, R.drawable.songPic5));
        songList.add(new Song("Name6", R.raw.song6, R.drawable.songPic6));
        songList.add(new Song("Name7", R.raw.song7, R.drawable.songPic7));
        songList.add(new Song("Name8", R.raw.song8, R.drawable.songPic8));

        adapter = new SongAdapter(this, songList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                playSong(position);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void playSong(int position) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        }

        Song song = songList.get(position);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, song.getSongResourceId());
        mediaPlayer.start();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Now Playing：" + song.getSongTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Pause Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

(SongAdapter.java)
package com.example.songbuttoninlistview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class SongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Song> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Song> songList;

    public SongAdapter(Context context, List<Song> songs) {
        super(context, 0, songs);
        this.songList = songs;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.songTitleTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.MusicName);
            viewHolder.playButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            viewHolder.musicPicture = convertView.findViewById(R.id.MusicPic);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Song song = getItem(position);

        viewHolder.songTitleTextView.setText(song.getSongTitle());
        viewHolder.musicPicture.setImageResource(song.getMusic_icon());

        viewHolder.playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MainActivity) getContext()).playSong(position);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView songTitleTextView;
        ImageView musicPicture;
        ImageButton playButton;
    }
}

(Song.java)
package com.example.songbuttoninlistview;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class Song {
    private String songTitle;
    private int songResourceId;
    private int music_icon;

    public Song(String songTitle, int songResourceId, int music_icon) {
        this.songTitle = songTitle;
        this.songResourceId = songResourceId;
        this.music_icon = music_icon;
    }

    public String getSongTitle() {
        return songTitle;
    }

    public int getSongResourceId() {
        return songResourceId;
    }

    public int getMusic_icon(){ return music_icon;}
}

thank for any help !!!
This below is my current project. . I made a Toolbar and bottom Navigation Bar. Bottom Bar can go to different pages (Fragment). Every pages have different function. Now I am trying to make Song Track List.
(ForthFragment.java)
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ForthFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView listView; // Declare a ListView variable
    private SongAdapter adapter; // Declare a SongAdapter variable
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer; // Declare a MediaPlayer variable
    private List<Song> songList; // Declare a List variable to hold songs

    public ForthFragment(){
        // Empty public constructor required
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forth, container, false); // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.lv); // Get reference to the ListView
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); // Create a new MediaPlayer
        songList = new ArrayList<>(); // Create a new List to hold the songs

        // Add your songs to the songList
        songList.add(new Song("Name1", R.raw.song1, R.drawable.songPic1));
        songList.add(new Song("Name2", R.raw.song2, R.drawable.songPic2));
        songList.add(new Song("Name3", R.raw.song3, R.drawable.songPic3));
        songList.add(new Song("Name4", R.raw.song4, R.drawable.songPic4));
        songList.add(new Song("Name5", R.raw.song5, R.drawable.songPic5));
        songList.add(new Song("Name6", R.raw.song6, R.drawable.songPic6));
        songList.add(new Song("Name7", R.raw.song7, R.drawable.songPic7));
        songList.add(new Song("Name8", R.raw.song8, R.drawable.songPic8));

        adapter = new SongAdapter(getActivity(), songList); // Create a new SongAdapter with the songList
        listView.setAdapter(adapter); // Set the adapter on the ListView

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                playSong(position); // Call the playSong() method when a song is clicked
            }
        });
        return view; // Return the inflated view
    }

    protected void playSong(int position) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) { // Check if MediaPlayer is currently playing a song
            mediaPlayer.pause(); // Pause the currently playing song
            mediaPlayer.release(); // Release the resources used by MediaPlayer
            mediaPlayer.reset(); // Reset the MediaPlayer to its uninitialized state
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); // Create a new instance of MediaPlayer
        }

        //AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);  Get AudioManager instance
        //audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);  Set the volume level to 20

        Song song = songList.get(position); // Get the selected song from the list
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), song.getSongResourceId()); // Create MediaPlayer with the selected song
        mediaPlayer.start(); // Start playing the song

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Now playing：" + song.getSongTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Display a toast with the currently playing song

    }
}

(SongAdapter.java)
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import java.util.List;

public class SongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Song> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Song> songList;

    public SongAdapter(Context context, List<Song> songs) {
        super(context, 0, songs);
        this.songList = songs;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false); // MAYBE THIS LINE WRONG

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.songTitleTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.MusicName);
            viewHolder.playButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.PlayMusicButton);
            viewHolder.musicPicture = convertView.findViewById(R.id.MusicPic);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Song song = getItem(position);

        viewHolder.songTitleTextView.setText(song.getSongTitle());
        viewHolder.musicPicture.setImageResource(song.getMusic_icon());

        viewHolder.playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity) getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();// this line may wrong
                ForthFragment forthFragment = (ForthFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("ForthFragment");// Call a method in the fragment
                if (forthFragment != null) {
                    forthFragment.playSong(position);
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView songTitleTextView;
        ImageView musicPicture;
        ImageButton playButton;
    }
}

(Song.java)
public class Song {
    private String songTitle;
    private int songResourceId;
    private int music_icon;

    public Song(String songTitle, int songResourceId, int music_icon) {
        this.songTitle = songTitle;
        this.songResourceId = songResourceId;
        this.music_icon = music_icon;
    }

    public String getSongTitle() {
        return songTitle;
    }

    public int getSongResourceId() {
        return songResourceId;
    }

    public int getMusic_icon(){ return music_icon;}
}


(fragment_forth.xml)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ForthFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewMusic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="78dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="Song Playlist:"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

(ListView layout :  list_item.xml)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/musicItems"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/MusicPic"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="Photo"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MusicName"
            android:layout_width="105dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/PlayMusicButton"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#FDF6FE"
            android:contentDescription="Play and Pause"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play_green_foreground" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

no error message. When I click the ImageButton , no audio play.
